# Finding prime numbers without using "prime characters"

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source, primes

Your task, if you choose to accept it, is to write a program/function that accepts an integer \$N\$ as input. The program/function should output/return a list of the first \$N\$ prime numbers. But here's the catch: you are not allowed to use *prime characters* in your code. A prime character is a character whose Unicode code point is a prime number. In the printable ASCII range, these are:

```
%)+/5;=CGIOSYaegkmq
```

But the rule also applies to non-ASCII characters if your code uses those.

- A valid input is an integer \$N\$ where \$0 < N \le T\$, where you can choose \$T\$, but it has to be greater than or equal to \$10000\$. \$T\$ does not have to be finite.
- For invalid inputs (non-integers, integers out of range), throw an exception or output/return nothing/null.
- An integer with leading/trailing whitespace as input is considered invalid.
- An integer with a `+` as sign character as input is considered invalid.
- An integer with leading zeros as input is considered valid.
- If your language allows you to pass an already-parsed integer as input, the above parsing rules (except the range one) don't apply, because the int is already parsed.
- The input is always base-10.
- Use of built-in prime generators and primality testers (this includes prime factorization functions) is not allowed.
- The source restriction is imposed on Unicode characters, but the byte counting for the score can be in another encoding if you wish.
- The output can contain a single trailing newline, but this is not required.
- If you output/return the prime number list as a string, then every prime number must be delimited by one or multiple non-digit char(s). You can choose which delimiter you use.
- This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, the shortest code in bytes wins.

### Stack Snippet to verify your code

You can use the below Stack Snippet to verify that your code does not contain prime chars:

```js
var primes=[],max=10000;for(var i=2;i<=max;i++){primes.push(i);}for(var N=2;N<Math.sqrt(max);N++){if(primes.indexOf(N)===-1){continue;}primes=primes.filter(function (x){return x===N||x%N!==0;});}function setText(elem,text){var z=('innerText' in elem)? 'innerText' : 'textContent';elem[z]=text;}function verify(inputCode,resultSpan){var invalidChars=[];var success=true;for(var i=0;i<inputCode.length;i++){var cc = inputCode.charCodeAt(i);if (cc>max){setText(resultSpan,"Uh oh! The char code was bigger than the max. prime number calculated by the snippet.");success = false;break;}if (primes.indexOf(cc)!==-1){invalidChars.push(inputCode[i]);}}if (invalidChars.length===0&&success){setText(resultSpan, "Valid code!");}else if(success) {  var uniqueInvalidChars = invalidChars.filter(function (x, i, self){return self.indexOf(x)===i;});setText(resultSpan, "Invalid code! Invalid chars: " + uniqueInvalidChars.join(""));    }}document.getElementById("verifyBtn").onclick=function(e){e=e||window.event;e.preventDefault();var code=document.getElementById("codeTxt").value;verify(code,document.getElementById("result"));};
```

```html
Enter your code snippet here:<br /><textarea id="codeTxt" rows="5" cols="70"></textarea><br /><button id="verifyBtn">Verify</button><br /><span id="result"></span>
```

Comment: It's pretty cruel that `;` happens to be banned...

Comment: If primality testers aren't allowed, what about prime factorization functions.

Comment: @Maltysen From prime factorization functions, you can very quickly see whether a number is a prime or not, so I'm afraid that's disallowed. I'll clarify that.

Comment: Are we mandated to throw out some of these invalid inputs? For instance, if our language's string->int function allows a leading `+`, it seems disappointing to be required to manually throw these out.

Comment: @Runer112 You don't have to throw. As the rules state, you can also simply exit/return with no/empty output.

Comment: @ProgramFOX My point is, I'm going to have to add code to disallow what my language thinks (and I think) is a valid integer, but that your spec doesn't. And that seems a bit silly. I would suggest that the spec presented a more minimal set of valid/invalid input rules, and left the rest up to user's choice.

Comment: I got all excited about this and started on a solution, then realized closed parens are disallowed. Well, I'm out.

Comment: @Runer112 I changed the rules and now the input range is 0 < N <= T, where you can choose T, but it has to be greater than or equal to 10000. This rule change does not invalidate existing answers.

Comment: @ProgramFOX But we're still required to treat inputs that start with a `+` as invalid, even if our language's string->int function parses them fine?

Comment: @Runer112 Yes, you are. I will not drop that requirement, because it makes a nice addition and makes the challenge a bit more difficult.

Comment: Do we have to treat multiple lines of input as invalid as well?

Comment: @Runer112 How do you mean, multiple lines? Just trailing/leading newlines, or the integer split up?

Comment: @ProgramFOX I assumed trailing/leading, since if the integer was split up, then it seems that the input couldn't be treated as a valid integer anyways.

Comment: @Runer112 In that case, it's invalid. I'll change "spaces" into "whitespace".

Comment: I bet it's possible in Brainfuck. But you'd have to use subtraction instead of addition. Nvm, it'd be easier to just use Blub.

Comment: In groovy, got this far `it.findAll{x->y=2..x**0.5;y.every{x%it}}​` then realized % was one of the characters excluded and facepalmed...

Comment: In JavaScript, you can't possibly assign an object, as `=` is banned, so you'd have to make it a single expression. In addition, you can't call a function with `()` (or make a function in any way), so you'd have to use tagged templates. I'd be surprised if it's actually possible. (Note: You can start by getting input with ```pro\u006dpt`` ```.)

Comment: @ETHproductions You can make a function using ``Function`...` ``. It's not very useful since it can't take any arguments, but it is possible. You could probably use some sort of escape sequence inside that template literal to assign to variables as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## CJam, <s>19</s> <s>18</s> <s>30</s> <s>34</s> <s>33</s> <s>19</s> <s>17</s> <s>21</s> 20 bytes

[Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=5%7B_3%5C%23%2C2%3E__ff*%3A~-%3CN*%7D~)

```
{_3\#,2>__ff*:~-<N*}
```

This is probably one of the most horribly inefficient algorithms I've ever implemented. But I did it for the size!

My answer consists of a code block, which acts like an anonymous function in CJam. Run it with an integer immediately preceding it on the stack, and the resulting list is dumped onto the stack. I treat the upper bound on the input as infinite so I don't have to check that bound.

My algorithm starts by raising 3 to the `input`th power, which is guaranteed to give a number larger than the `input`-th prime if the input is valid. Then a list of the integers from 2 to this number minus one is generated, which is a large enough swath to contain all the prime numbers we want. To get rid of the composite numbers... *sigh*... we create a list of every pairwise product, which should generate all composite numbers from 4 to some stupidly large value, large enough for our purposes. Then it's just a matter of removing every element from the original list that is in this composite list, trimming it down to the first `input` elements, and joining the elements with the newline character.

The algorithm *should* work for any input. However, whether or not the interpreter/computer has enough memory or time is a whole other question, because the time and space requirements are exponential with respect to the input. So if the input is larger than about 5 for the online interpreter or about 8 for the offline one, then the answer to that question is probably no.

Comment: heh, at 17 you have a prime number of bytes in your answer.

Comment: Why do you need a `S*`?

Comment: @user23013 Invalid inputs less than 1 still feed through the algorithm, they just produce an empty list. But that's not a legal output for them, so I join the list elements with spaces to produce an empty output for these invalid inputs.

Comment: I've noticed this, isn't `S` a prime character?

Comment: It is a prime character. I *know* I'm over 2 years late on saying this, but this answer should be *invalid*

Comment: @ZacharyT You're right, I don't know how I and everybody else missed that. I have amended the solution to use `N` instead. This results in the output being newline-delimited instead of space-delimited.

Comment: Thanks, I replaced my downvote with an upvote now, nice work! (I came back here to see if anything's changed, then I realized that I left a trailing space at the end of one of my lines)!

Answer (score 15):

## Python 3.7+, 183 bytes

```python
for E,E.__clªss_ᵍᵉtitᵉᵐ__ in[__builtins__.__loªdᵉr__,ᵉxᵉc],:E[f'd{101:c}f F(n\x29:\n p,f\x3d1,1\n whil{101:c} n>0:p,f\x3d-~p,f*p*p\73n-\x3df{37:c}p>0!\x3dprint(p\x29']
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYxBCoMwEEWvkq5qJZakWUizcKeXMDJQJRiQGDSlFmn3XRR6DvdewJt4kjSCi5k////HmKetW82ck22HUpyeAcpmmfoe1vm7zh@rrN/r/ANASucAt7tqrNI9gEebdpkq33cA2MvgpywwT3N5rEZKKC9fEmWBFsPlyoVGBksxsIpi6s2jVs0OIZ0QvpfR2x@hCY2ImY62RI4s9pBJyGGzplPaBmb7eSxcFlBycn8)

Assumes an infinite upper bound, takes integer input via function argument, and prints the primes on separate lines.

Without substitutions for characters (except `\n`):

```python
for E,E.__class_getitem__ in[__builtins__.__loader__,exec],:E[f'def F(n):\n p,f=1,1\n while n>0:p,f=-~p,f*p*p;n-=f%p>0!=print(p)']
```

The string in the above code:

```python
def F(n):
 p,f=1,1
 while n>0:p,f=-~p,f*p*p;n-=f%p>0!=print(p)
```

Python 3.7 [added](https://peps.python.org/pep-0560/) the `__class_getitem__` magic method: if `A` is a class, then `A[x]` calls `A.__class_getitem__(x)`. Assigning `exec` to this attribute of a class allows us to call it without `)`. Unfortunately, we cannot create our own class without either using the `class` keyword (`a`) or calling the `type` function (`)`), so we must use a built-in class. The only one that allows the assignment to be made without error is `__builtins__.__loader__`.

Python [normalizes](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers) all identifiers to NFKC, and this allows us to spell `__class_getitem__`, `__loader__`, and  `exec` without using any of the letters `aegm`. The exact substitutions are U+00AA for `a`, U+1D49 for `e`, U+1D4D for `g`, and U+1D50 for `m`. We use a `for` loop to make assignments without using `=`, and these let us call `exec` via `E[f'...']` in the body.

Inside the string passed to `exec`, we use octal (`\73` instead of `;`), hex (`\x3d` instead of `=`), and decimal (`{37:c}` instead of `%`) escapes for banned characters. The code simply tests the primality of each positive integer using [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem). A function was used instead of a lambda as the recursion limit causes the latter to stop working well below 10000.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice first answer!

Answer (score 9):

## Java. 474 bytes

```java
i\u006dport j\u0061v\u0061.util.*\u003bvoid b(int b\u0029{Lon\u0067 c\u003d2L,d,f[]\u003d{}\u003bfor(f\u003dArr\u0061ys.copy\u004ff(f,b\u0029,Arr\u0061ys.fill(f,0L\u0029\u003bb-->0\u003b\u0029for(d\u003d0L\u003bf[b]<1\u003bf[b]\u003dd<1?c:f[b],d\u003d0L,c\u002b\u002b\u0029for(lon\u0067 h:f\u0029d\u003dh>0&&c\u002fh*h\u003d\u003dc?1:d\u003bj\u0061v\u0061x.x\u006dl.bind.JAXB.un\u006d\u0061rsh\u0061l(""\u002bArr\u0061ys.\u0061sList(f\u0029,Lon\u0067.cl\u0061ss\u0029\u003b}
```

Takes input via function argument, outputs via thrown exception.

Indented:

```java
i\u006dport j\u0061v\u0061.util.*\u003b
void b(int b\u0029{
    Lon\u0067 c\u003d2L,d,f[]\u003d{}\u003b
    for(f\u003dArr\u0061ys.copy\u004ff(f,b\u0029,Arr\u0061ys.fill(f,0L\u0029\u003bb-->0\u003b\u0029
        for(d\u003d0L\u003bf[b]<1\u003bf[b]\u003dd<1?c:f[b],d\u003d0L,c\u002b\u002b\u0029
            for(lon\u0067 h:f\u0029
                d\u003dh>0&&c\u002fh*h\u003d\u003dc?1:d\u003b
    j\u0061v\u0061x.x\u006dl.bind.JAXB.un\u006d\u0061rsh\u0061l(""\u002bArr\u0061ys.\u0061sList(f\u0029,Lon\u0067.cl\u0061ss\u0029\u003b
}
```

Escaped characters removed:

```java
import java.util.*;
void b(int b){
    Long c=2L,d,f[]={};
    for(f=Arrays.copyOf(f,b),Arrays.fill(f,0L);b-->0;)
        for(d=0L;f[b]<1;f[b]=d<1?c:0,d=0L,c++)
            for(long h:f)
                d=h>0&&c/h*h==c?1:d;
    javax.xml.bind.JAXB.unmarshal(""+Arrays.asList(f),Long.class);
}
```

Explanation:

```java
Long c,d,f[]={};                                                //Initialize variables.

for(f=java.util.Arrays.copyOf(f,b),Arrays.fill(f,0L);b-->0;)
    f=java.util.Arrays.copyOf(f,b),Arrays.fill(f,0L)            //Initialize f to an array of 0's.
                                                     b-->0      //Iterate over the first b primes.

for(d=0L;f[b]<1;f[b]=d<1?c:0,d=0L,c++)
    d=0L                        d=0L                            //Initialize d to 0.
         f[b]<1                      c++                        //Increment c while the b'th prime is 0.
                f[b]=d<1?c:0                                    //If d = 0, the b'th prime = c, else continue.

for(long h:f)                                                   //Iterate over all found primes.

d=h>0&&c/h*h==c?1:d;
  h>0                                                           //Ignore non-found primes.
       c/h*h==c                                                 //Equivalent to c%h==0
               ?1:d                                             //If h is prime and c is divisible by h, d = 1. Otherwise d stays unchanged.

javax.xml.bind.JAXB.unmarshal(""+Arrays.asList(f),Long.class)   //Print solution to stderr
javax.xml.bind.JAXB.unmarshal(                   ,Long.class)   //Prints what's contained to stderr.
                                 Arrays.asList(f)               //Convert f to list.
                              ""+                               //Convert to string.
```

My original solution used a `return` statement. After asking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28635275/4230423) on StackOverflow, [regettman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1707091/rgettman) was kind enough to provide a way to output/return without using prime letters.

As usual, suggestions are welcome :)

Comment: +1. That had to be really hard for you and rgettman to figure out. Very impressive. :)

Answer (score 6):

## Ruby, 74

```
->n,*o{o<<[2..n*n][0].find{|x|!o.find{|y|1.>x.^y.*x.div y}}until o[n-1]
o}
```

Explanation:

`*o` initializes an empty output array. until it has `n` items, we find the smallest number >=2  that doesn't divide any item currently in `o`, then add it to `o`. To test for division, yikes. All the good operators are disallowed, and I can't even use `divmod`. Best I could see was to use `x.div y`, which takes x divided by y and rounds down, then multiply that by y again. If it equals x, there was no rounding, so y divides x. `1.>x.^` is an equality test, checking whether the result of xor is 0. The `.` before every operator is because you can't mix `.`-free operator calls and parenthesis-free method calls.

Edit: The range-checking specifications were added after I posted this, I think. To comply requires 79 characters:

```
->n,*o{o<<[*2..-~n*n].find{|x|!o.find{|y|1.>x.^y.*x.div y}}until o[n-1]||n<1
o}
```

Answer (score 4):

## CJam, <s>38</s> <s>37</s> 30 bytes

```
{_~2#,2>\{(\{1$37c~},\p}*'<(~}
```

[Try it here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=10%0A%7B_~2%23%2C2%3E%5C%7B(%5C%7B1%2437c~%7D%2C%5Cp%7D*'%3C(~%7D%0A~)

I think this should comply with all the rules and works for any non-negative *N* (i.e. *T* is infinite). It's horribly inefficient though, so don't try it for large numbers.

This is a block - the closest thing to an (unnamed) function - which expects an integer on the stack, prints all the prime numbers and leaves the stack without its input. For all invalid inputs it will either throw an error or print nothing.

Most of the code is input validation, followed by the sieve of Eratosthenes. I only needed to work around the input restriction in 3 places:

- `)` is increment in CJam. I needed that once, but could replace it with `~` (bitwise complement) because I was squaring the numbers afterwards anyway.
- `%` is modulo. I'm using `37c~` instead, which first creates the character `%` and then eval's that. This makes the code a lot slower.
- `;` pops and discards an element from the stack. I need to do this at the end. Instead I'm using `'<(~` which pushes the character `<`, decrements it and eval's that.

Comment: I thought that, given all the input parsing rules, we're not allowed to just take in an already-parsed integer.

Comment: @Runer112 We're allowed to write "a function which accepts an integer". Not "a function which accepts the string representation of an integer".

Answer (score 4):

## Bash + coreutils, 227 bytes

```
printf -vb br`dc<<<Di14B8209P`
printf -vc -- $[$1-0]
[ "${1#$c}" -o $c -lt 1 ]||{
for i in {2..104729}
{
for f in `jot $[i-1] $[i-1] 1`
{
[ 0 -lt `dc<<<"$i $f~p"` ]||$b
}
[ $f -lt 2 ]&&printf $i\ &&: $[c--]
[ $c -lt 1 ]&&$b
}
}
```

This was quite tricky.  Some things I ran into:

- Most loops (`while` and `until`) are unusable because they most close with `done` which is a shell keyword and cannot be the result of a variable expansion (unless `eval` is used, but that is out too).  The only usable loop is `for`/`in` which allows `{`/`}` instead of `do`/`done`.  `for (( ; ; ))` is also not usable.
- `=` is out, so we need another way to assign variables.  `printf -v` is good for this.
- We know that p(10000) is 104729 so for the outer loop for potential primes we can simply loop from 2 to 104729 and break once we have enough primes
- `jot` generates the list of potential factors in the inner loop.  If a potential factor divides a potential prime, then it is not prime and we break out early
- Fortunately `break` is a shell builtin and not a keyword, so may be generated as a result of an expansion.  `dc` converts a base 13 number to the bytestream `eak`.
- To check if a potential factor divides a potential prime, we cannot use the usual `/` or `%` shell arithmetic operators.  So this is outsourced to `dc`s `~` operator, which pushes quotient and remainder to the stack.
- `-lt` - less-than - is the only usable shell comparison operator.
- `echo` is no use for output.  `printf` works though as long as we avoid `%`

Getting the input validation right is a bit of a pain.  This returns nothing in the case of invalid input.

#### Output:

```
$ ./primenoprime.sh 10
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 $
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), <strike>2720</strike> 1695 bytes

```rust
|n|for i in 0..n{if i<3&&i>1||i&1>0&&0<[0x2196820D864A4c32816D129A64B4cB6Eu128,0x4A2882D129861144A48961204A0434c9|1<<28,0x148A48844224064B0834992132424030|1<<80,0x64048928124108A00B40B4086c304204|1<<0|1<<84|1<<120,0xc02104c94112422180124496804c3098,0x220824B0826896810804490000982D32|1<<104,0x69009244304340069004264940A28948|1<<36,0x86122D22400c06012410DA408088210,0x14916022c044A0020110D301821B0484,0x4cA2100800422094092094D204A6400c|1<<84,0x34c108144309A24A48B081041018200|1<<28|1<<64,0x241140A2180032402084490880422402|1<<8|1<<20|1<<68,0x29260008360044120A41A00101840128|1<<72,0xc20c26484822006D10100480c0618283|1<<100,0x10c02402190024884420482024894810|1<<44|1<<7*8|1<<104,0x60901300264B0400802832cA01140868,0x430800112186430c32100100D0248082|1<<16,0x24880906002D20430092900c10480424,0x4000814196800880430082090932c040|1<<60,0x926094022080c3292048489608481048|1<<4*13,0xA04204901904004A0104422812000|1<<7*8,0x800084424002982c02c801348348924|1<<96,0x1864328244908A0004D0048442043698|1<<28|1<<112,0x861104309204A44028024001020A0090,0x4424990912486084c90804422c004208|1<<36,0x4040208804321A011000211403002400|1<<88,0xA2020c90116802186030014084c30906,0x8801904800841028224148929860004,0x120100100c061061020004A442681210,0x140128040A0c94186412422194032010|1<<7*8,0x4882402D20410490014000D040A40A29,0x822902002484490424080130100020c1|1<<76,0xA0cA0006112100104816814802486100|1<<20,0x2414480906810c044200B09104000240|1<<120,0x84420004802c10c860A00A011242092|1<<16|1<<112,0x12824414814804820022130406980032,0x2c00D86424812004D028804340101824,0x180110c04120cA41020000A241081209,0x48044320240A08320941220A41804A4,0x820104128864008A6086400c001800|1<<96][i>>8]&1<<{[i&{1<<8}-1][0]>>1}{print!{"{}
",i}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVTbahtBDH33V2zzYJKQBkkjJprWNaxxv8L4ISwxLLRuyQVCbX@7e442xQ1mY89qRuemeX57eT3v9t3Px3F/fXOY/Xh67XZfdvvrt5fxz9NN9607H/fH3a/nbuzGfSf39/vDuOvGRZnPx6Uej@NclzKfy2Ij76athsk6qvc@FAuta7XWV1/5sKrf39TiTt69twjjm6iqjtpoVU28Fy8@tKMuFlmoHngX7mYuOESieGumxRwLRVgYgsLqgjPQz1wlepGV8xN1KOI4mIVTdX5FL8IQU0E7V2wz0xD8dzDAYpFGAGYSxr5WATFwtqBC8NdAoFgeJk4EWG3YXkhBhD/dqjcXkG0erCwVhaBstiYhGaRKIl73wCrQRCVZN61iNqAXqJgoKoooXq9Ak9186FGLPWhigiaNzzUlrDx4oopCyAnQSlytNyoNMkCsPE5kUprPympgUQKGFAKN0TpIN0LSgaSb1ZY7a0rUrEKPKHi6Q9neFajZwMEuyx@MmE0GKBIegCwIBmpAhyoAS5RJyxQAa2ynENEm/1Fo/A4lNXt7GvlwG/9ZIE20YAuT4lQHp9rQC0lFgoUMoAa/FREtgogqocqaZ8PlPKymEiDd4I8YVS00F2ggplOM9ICs1Rl5SYlQBJBNWqF1k0JJBwLBImaJHRvJMPEQl1YkA7/VgtI@0woajQTgPt5DeuRaJrNAmBlia@cMCGYI3WxAeItjPDAFqUwji2RpYWkiTBFfU/LUs9QWF/shCRVE0pgU5siBOGgDMMBUCJAzg6YNFBHbIIGh5UgwrIR@iTkGkvGhLKa0AN2NRtAgn8jEx4ghGKCs0JG@sIKG5RBKjkykIJQZwQUf5JREcX2QU0osk5EMEz/Uixwwt/pvqphGoOqFIw9lpqmHM4W7L@rCeqaPvivNIBpGBFs5HC1BN7Ywz/mgEdRfkiRCkmdljGSg7JWJIz4YDkBOXXEPfMyfTJPnnokLpp8OyQoyMwbU63JrpXs5OIY0DpAAHSgw2MC5KcEXSzXtR0t25RAhh0CK67TlkLM3vOOVDUzMGTJi6ZvnEGfWeTcmLiUjn/SFFrxtsdRSNaAuHFKgwdwh8rjoeBsEnSByyozFCN5R0SM/eVlBmJikaHW7GZfL2M7x47AZ5wem5PRZtxvZLpd6Ovx@Hvevnw5Xh9Ps6m48nU7nr7PdNXWXm9np/Bc)

[Lookup table generator](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=d00e709d3560207c376d52d5bce8648f)

Yikes, I'm fairly confident rust doesn't even count as primitive recursive with the restrictions, because mutability and function calls are disallowed, meaning there is no way to maintain state across loop iterations. Works up to 10111.

My strategy was to form a lookup table by packing the primality of every odd number into array of 128 bit integers, and then just using a good old fashioned mask and shift to recover the value. The `5`s in the hexadecimal representation are dealt with by removing the 1 bit and orring it in at runtime. To deal with operator precedence issues, I abused the fact that blocks are also expressions, so I can use curly braces instead of parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, 90 bytes

```
\n->[fst c|c<-zip[p|p<-[2..],not$or[b>p-1&&b-1<p|b<-[u*v|u<-[2..p-1],v<-[2..p-1]]]][1..n]]
```

This is an anonymous function which takes an integer `n` as input.

How it works: `[p|p<-[2..],not$or[b>p-1&&b-1<p|b<-[u*v|u<-[2..p-1],v<-[2..p-1]]]]` (first example of prime number one-liners at the [Haskell wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Prime_numbers_miscellaneous#One-liners) but with the `elem` function replaced) creates an infinite list of primes. `zip` it with the numbers from `1`to `n` to make a list of `(prime, seq. number)` pairs. Remove seq. number, again. Result is a list of primes of length `n`.

Answer (score 2):

## Rust, 64897 bytes

```rs
|n|println!{"{:?}",&[2,3,6-1,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,60-7,0x3b,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97,101,103,107,109,113,127,131,137,139,149,0x97,0x9d,163,167,173,179,181,191,193,197,199,211,223,227,229,233,239,241,0xfb,0x101 ...}
```

(code snipped due to character limit, [full solution here](https://gist.github.com/vintermann/863374c3114b4e421336a2b4ae06e9ec))

The following rust features become unavailable due to the prime restriction:

- function calls, as they require ')'
- regular bindings, since they require let (e)
- macro definitions, they require macro-rules! (a,e,m)
- match statements, they require match (a,m) and => (=)
- mutability, since it's always introduced with the mut keyword (m).
- return (e), break (a,e), continue (e)
- else (e)

What you can technically use:

- if. But without else, they're useless in expression contexts, so only good for side effects.
- macros. Standard macros like print! are usually followed by (), but it's actually legal to use {} or [] instead. Without this, the task would be impossible.
- closures, in the most narrow sense. You can't call them (requires ()) or bind them(requires let), but you can define a single non-recursive one. Without this, the task would obviously become impossible.
- structs.
- for loops. These are promising, since they actually allow variable binding, and they take an iterator, which can still be defined with the range syntax. The iterator can even be an expression.
- Builtin operators, except +, % and /. The short-circuiting logical operators seem promising.

I simply couldn't make anything Turing-complete with these tools. I'm sorry. All that was left was to include the full first 10000 primes, cleaned of 5's. At least you can slice it and have a valid solution, in the most narrow sense possible.

I very much would like experts on Turing tarpit diving (or on Rust!) to tell me if I could have done anything better!

Answer (score 1):

### GNU APL, <s>75 68 67 65 59 56</s> 55 characters

`⎕IO` must be `1`.

```
∇z←p n
z←2,j←3
j←j--2
→2×⍳∨⌿1>z|j
z←z,j
→2×⍳n>⍴z
z←n↑z∇
```

I came back on this months later realizing that I had an extra space!

Comment: Is this in APL encoding or UTF-8? If you convert it to APL encoding (and it's valid) it would be much shorter in bytes.

Comment: UTF-8. Yeah, but at those low character points, there's going to be more primes.

Comment: To be exact, it's now byte counted in APL, but it's restriction on source is Unicode. (I realized the challenge allowed non-Unicode byte counts)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
2ḍƇ`L<3Ʋ#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/o4Y7eY@0JPjbGxzYp////3xwA)

The character codes are `[50, 7693, 391, 96, 76, 60, 51, 434, 35]`

### How it works

```
2ḍƇ`L<3Ʋ# - Main link. Takes N on the left
       Ʋ  - Define a monad f(k):
  Ƈ       -   Filter the range [1, 2, ..., k] on the following:
 ḍ `      -     Divides k cleanly?
    L     -   Length
     <3   -   Less than 3?
2       # - Count up k = 2, 3, 4, ... until n integers return true. 
            Return those integers
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 131 bytes

```javascript
[].fill.constructor`M${`for(N\x3D1\x3bM\x3bn-N||--M-print(n\x29\x29for(n\x3Di\x3DN-\x3D-1\x3bi-->2\x3b\x29n\x2fi-~~[n\x2fi]||n--`}`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY5RT8IwFIXf/R2atczbAgLRLONFg@Fh44EnMxY2m5ZUa4vdXJY4@etzF554uF9Ocr6T3I@yKSvh9bGG5rFXMQmCkOzjJR/1Wc6UNoYJZ6va/4ja@SK5/S2U8yTdtQ8vkwHvCcJC2nUACRy9tjWxu3b6hIeqRVUjUkDCeaYBllMMqKGvNJxO2SXlXWcBir@iH/ExpawyWkiyuIcZjW7wHWckM@5AeHZHQz6P4ufX9Wb7VsrD59d3zplspSCKDvYqlk1phnw9XIVBgC2ZjGnU/wM)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](http://pyth.herokuapp.com) - 12 bytes

Uses pyth's prime factorization function to see if # is prime. Uses `!tPT` trick suggested to me at my answer for primes under million problem.

```
<f!tPTr2^T6Q
```

Since the filter only works for primes under n and not first n, I just looked up the inverse of pi(x) for 10,000 and got 104,000 so I use primes under 10⁶ and get first n. This doesn't actually run, so you should test by replacing `^T6` with `^T3` and restrict n to under 1000. Input from stdin and output to stdout.

```
<          Q     Slice first n
f     r2^T6      filter on range 2->10⁶
 !               Logical not (gives true if tail is empty)
  t              Tail (all but first, so gives empty if prime fact is len 1)
   PT            Prime factorization of filter var (len 1 if num is prime)
```

Comment: From the rules: "Use of built-in prime generators and primality testers is not allowed."

Comment: @Runer112 Yeah but this is not a primality tester, is prime factorization, is on the border of the rules. I should probably ask if this is allowed.

Comment: @Maltysen *"Use of built-in prime generators and primality testers (this includes prime factorization functions) is not allowed"* - seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma the clarification "(this includes prime factorization functions)" was added after this answer was posted.

Comment: MartinBüttner True.  I guess its up to @ProgramFOX'es discretion.

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
∞¦ʒDÑPQ}sôн
```

Input as integers.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AR4A4f9vc2FiaWX//@KInsKmypJEw5FQUX1zw7TQvf//MTA) or [verify it's valid, and some test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/a/0/1HHvEPLTk1yOTwxILC2@PCWC3v/Kx3a5q0UUJSfXpSYa6WgZG/LpeScn5KqW5CfmVdSrKCRmFepUFCUmZtabK8Jkj@0MvjoviNtxdku9koKj9omAYUKEMzDC3S4lIJSi0tzgHrT8osUog11DA1igRp1Qlz9DA/vgqv0O7ROL0znPwA).

Or 14 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) if we include string inputs, and comply to the other rules:

- Non-integer strings; leading whitespaces; or leading `+` are invalid
- Leading `0` are valid

```
∞ʒDÑPQ}s0ì>ôн¦
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f9vc2FiaWX//@KInsqSRMORUFF9czDDrD7DtNC9wqb//ys3) or [verify it's valid, and some test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/a/0/1HHvFOTXA5PDAisLTY4vMbu8JYLew8t@690aJu3UkBRfnpRYq6VgpK9LZeSc35Kqm5BfmZeSbGCRmJepUJBUWZuarG9Jkj@0Mrgo/uOtBVnu9grKTxqmwQUKkAwDy/Q4VIKSi0uzQHqTcsvUog21DE0iAVq1Alx9TM8vAuu0u/QOr0wnVoupeCC1OTMxByF5MTi1GKQQqWknEQlJQVzJSVtIDYAYqCAOUhQs6zyUcMypcP7lZBNqjw8AWzWfwA).

**Explanation:**

```python
∞        # Push an infinite positive list: [1,2,3,...]
 ¦       # Remove the leading 1: [2,3,4,...]
  ʒ      # Filter it by:
   D     #  Duplicate the current integer
    Ñ    #  Pop and push a list of its divisors
     P   #  Take the product of this list of divisors
      Q  #  Check if it's still the same as the duplicated integer
         #  (only if the divisors are {1,value}, the value will be a prime)
  }s     # After the filter: swap so the (implicit) input-integer is a the top
    ô    # Split the infinite list into parts of that size
     н   # Pop and leave just the first part
```

*For the program with additional string input validation:*

- The `0ì` will prepend a leading `"0"` to the input (to fix the test cases with leading `+`, which would otherwise be interpret as integers);
- The `>` will then increase the string-integer by 1 (implicitly converting it to an integer if it's valid first), because we haven't removed the leading `1` with `¦` yet;
- The `¦` will then:

  - Remove the leading `1` from the list for valid inputs;
  - Or remove the `1` from itself, leaving an empty string for invalid inputs. Because the `s0ì>ô` will have been no-ops, after which `н` will leave not the first part, but the first integer in the list, which is the `1`.

*Minor notes:*

1. Uses [05AB1E encoding](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage), with [the following codepoint-integers](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L4jbXpHGv//BwA).
2. `ôн` could have been `£`, but unfortunately `£` with code-point 163 is a prime.
3. Even if prime-builtins were allowed, `Å` in the builtin `Åp` with code-point 197 is a prime as well. Although `<ÝØ` would in that case be a short 'valid' alternative: [Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f5vDcwzP@/zcHAA) or [verify it's 'valid', and some test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/a/03@bw3MMz/isd2uatFFCUn16UmGuloGRvy6XknJ@SqluQn5lXUqygkZhXqVBQlJmbWmyvCZI/tDL46L4jbcXZLvZKCo/aJgGFChDMwwt0uJSCUotLc4B60/KLFKINdQwNYoEadUJc/QwP74Kr9Du0Ti9M5z8A). `<Ý` pushes a list in the range `[0,input)`, whereas `Ø` converts each value in this list to their 0-based value'th prime.